# how to populate a dropdown list forms?

Tags: python, django

help please fill in the drop down list dynamically form values ​​from the database.

models.py:

```
class Gender(models.Model):     
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, 
        blank=False,
    )   

    @classmethod
    def get_gender_list(self):
        return self.objects.all()
```

forms.py:

```
class SearchFriendsForm(forms.Form):
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select, 
        choices=Gender.get_gender_list(),   # not worked
        #choices=(('1', '1'), ('2', '2')),  # worked
        label='Пол',
    )
```

friends_search.html:

```
{{ form.gender }}
```

resulting error is displayed:

```
'Gender' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/userprofile/friends_search/
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'Gender' object is not iterable
Exception Location: C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py in render_options, line 528
```

Comment: this is solve problem. thnanks!

Answer (score 2):

In ChoiceField, `choices` works like this:

```
CHOICES=(
    ('id1', _("value1")),
    ('id2', _("value2")),
)
```

So, to get choices in your choice field `gender`, you have to build a list like above.

Here is how I do:

```
CHOICES=[]
for x in Gender.get_gender_list():
   CHOICES.append((x.id, x.gender))
```

Finally:

```
class SearchFriendsForm(forms.Form):
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select, 
        choices=CHOICES,
        label='Пол',
    )
```